# Rstudio to mysql arabic data corrupted

Tags: mysql, r, utf-8

I have a simple rscript to save the data from rstudio to mysql by calling a mysql stored procedure,

mysql is installed at linux server.

code snippet for saving is below

```
mydata<- levels(as.factor(datatable$ID[1]))
apply(ExportTable, 1, function(row) sqlQuery(mysqldb, sprintf("CALL spsavetoMysql('%s', '%s', %s, '%s', '%s', %s, '%s', '%s', '%s')", pid, rid, row[1], gsub("'", "''", row[3]), row[2], row[4], sid, gsub("'", "''", row[6]), gsub("'", "''", row[5]) )))
```

But when i use arabic character it corrupt data like

when data is being sent from rstudio data are correct,

when manually calling sp in mysql, data inserts successfully,

it corrupt data on the way calling mysql sp from r script.

please advise.

Thanks

Comment: This behavior doesn't show in vanilla R?